# Can I do Pearson cross-correlation between two time series of Twitter data without violating the assumptions?

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r, cross-correlation, social-network

I have a dataset of Tweets regarding a given topic (extracted by predefined keywords and hashtags). I aggregated the Tweets in bins of time (e.g. every ten minutes) to generate a time series of the activity in the discussion. Based on a filtering process I derived a set of users that is supposedly influential in the given discussion (let's call them influencers). Now I want to check if there is a (lagged) correlation between the activity of the influencers and the remaining users in the dataset (activity just means that a user Tweets or Retweets). So I wonder if we can show that influencers post earlier than the remaining users? While working on this problem I faced multiple problems regarding the assumption of regular Pearson correlation:

1. The variables must be randomly sampled and independent
2. The variables must be normally distributed
3. There must be a linear relationship between the variables
4. The variables have no outliers

Here is a brief summary of how I treat the data:

1. Resampling the data to a given time step (e.g. 10 min) to have equal time step size which is necessary for applying the cross correlation later - by this I introduce a lot of zero values to the data. I use pandas library for that and sum all Tweets that appeared in a given time step.
2. Decomposing the dataset into trend, seasonality and residuals to achieve stationarity of the data and not only show circadian behaviour in my correlations.
3. Treating outliers and log transforming data.
4. Split up the dataset into the influencer activity time series and the remaining user time series.
5. Calculate cross correlation for multiple time lags.

Here is the doubts that I currently have:

**Independence**:
Assuming that users in a Twitter conversation are already connected, if an influencer makes a post this post probably appears on the Feed of at least some of the remaining users - meaning that their tweeting behaviour is not independent. So is the approach of making a correlation analysis here already mislead? If yes - which other approach would you recommend to analyse the previously shown research interest?

**Normality, Outliers and zero values**: Due to the resampling I have a lot of zero values in my dataset. Because of that and due to the nature of the data the activity distributions are power law distributed. After doing the decomposition and the residuals have a poisson-ish distribution with a long tail. In order to meet the assumptions of Pearson distribution I log transform the data and remove the outliers. Two fundamental questions arise from this:

1. Is it valid that I simply do the log transformation by adding a constant c=1 (i.e. log(x+1)) in order to keep zero values but still normalize my transformation?
2. Should I do the data treatment before splitting up my time series or afterwards and on each of the time series (Influencers and remaining users) separately?
   --> Following these problems would it be smarter to use spearman rank correlation?

**Zero Values**: When I resample my data (see step one above) I introduce a lot of zero values into the dataset. Also when I split up my data into influencers and remaining users there is even more zero values in each time series. Especially the influencer dataset contains a lot of zero values as it is a small set of users. These zero values stay in my distribution and create an ugly peak in an else wise pretty much normally distributed dataset. Which influence do these values have on my correction, do they valuate my assumption and how can I cope with them?

**Randomness**: I assume that the tweeting behavior contains a lot of noise where peoplee are just occasionally tweeting. The lagged correlation that I want to show (influencers posting before the remaining users) mainly appears during generally highly active times. If I do not remove the noise it probably hides the behavior I want to show. Is there reasonably methods to remove this noise systematically and not just setting an arbitrary threshold?

The following graph shows the distribution of the split up time series (left=Influencer, right=remaining users). First row is the residuals of the original data, second row is the log transformed data and third row shows box plots of both time series (outliers were removed on the combined time series) and the residuals distribution of liner fit x->y.

I am very happy for any help. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Hopefully someone can come along with more of a thorough answer, because you ask a lot of questions. But it's not true that the data must be normally distributed and must contain no outliers in order for Pearson correlation to be valid. those assumptions might be required to perform specific statistical inferences and analyses, but in the general case it's perfectly valid to compute Pearson correlation on any arbitrary data.

Comment: However it sounds like you are asking about statistical analysis, possibly even causal inference, and there are other concerns not directly related to the distribution of the data, such as ensuring that you don't obtain spurious causal inferences from two unrelated time series that happen to be trending in the same direction.

Comment: You might also be interested in the concept of Granger causality.

Comment: @shadowtalker thanks a lot for the fast answers. I tried to remove trends in the time series by decomposing them previously and only using the residual part. I hope that is what you are referring to by spurious causal inference? Thanks for the hints, I will read myself into these concepts.